# Firebase 'overrides nothing' after dependency update

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies

After dependency updates to latest versions (core, auth, database...) we get 500+ errors in our older (2018) in-production Android app.

e.g.

```
"Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member @PublicApi public abstract fun onDataChange(@NonNull p0: DataSnapshot): Unit defined in com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener"
"Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected"
"Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type DatabaseReference?"
"Smart cast to 'String' is impossible, because 'order.locationId' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time"
"Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter K in inline operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V): Unit"
....
```

There is no way in this world we are going line by line only to remove '?' or add '!!' in whole project, not to mention testing and pushing the update on production.....

Is there a way to fix it, or we should just stick with 2018 dependencies and SDK 27, because, you know, *it's just a usual Google thing*?

EDIT:

- Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member @PublicApi public abstract fun onCancelled(@NonNull p0: DatabaseError): Unit defined in com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

  ```
  private val connectionListener = object : ValueEventListener {
  override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
  }

  override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {

      connected = p0?.getValue(Boolean::class.java)!!

      if (connected) {

          disconnectReference?.child(resources.getString(R.string.offline))?.setValue(false)
          disconnectReference?.child(resources.getString(R.string.offline))?.onDisconnect()?.setValue(true) { error, _ ->
              if (error != null)
                  Log.e(this@ApplicationInventoryManagement.javaClass.simpleName, resources.getString(R.string.on_disconnect_event))
          }
          disconnectReference?.child(resources.getString(R.string.last_sync))?.onDisconnect()?.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)

      }

  }
  ```

  }

fix is removing '?' from overridden methods parameters, the same thing on 100+ places in project

- Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter K in inline operator fun  MutableMap.set(key: K, value: V): Unit

  ```
  private val productEventListener = object : EventListenerWithBroadcast() {

  override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

      productsLoaded = false
      val productChange = Intent(ApplicationInventoryManagement.FIREBASE_DATA_CHANGE)

      doAsync {

          dataSnapshot.children
                  .filterNotNull()
                  .forEach { products!![it.key] = it.getValue(Product::class.java)!! }

          if (sendBroadcast) {

              productChange.putExtra(ApplicationInventoryManagement.TYPE, ApplicationInventoryManagement.PRODUCTS)
              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this@ActivityMain).sendBroadcast(productChange)

          }
          productsLoaded = true

      }

  }

  override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
  ```

  }

fix is adding '!!' to map key "products!![it.key!!]" because now it doesn't want to be nullable

- Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type DatabaseReference?

  `ref.parent.child("selected").setValue(false)`

fix is adding '?' after parent "ref.parent?.child..." because now it wants to be nullable, or non-null asserted with '!!'

- Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

  ```
                  val key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.vehicles)
                      .child(vehicleKey)
                      .child("log")
                      .push().key
  ```

fix is adding '!!' on first child key ".child(vehicleKey!!)..." and so on...

Comment: Provide more details and example code. I have no problems with latest Firebase (database, auth, crashlytics) on Java and AndroidX, target SDK 28.

Comment: added some code examples